# Replacing special characters in Python

Tags: python

How can I replace these characters in Python2.7 with comma:

|
•

something like this does not work:

```
a= b.replace("|", ",")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Regular expression which contains list of characters to be replaced

```
import re
a = re.sub(u'[|•]', ',', a)
```

**SYNTAX:**

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, max=0)
```

This method replace all occurrences of the RE pattern in string with repl, substituting all occurrences unless *max* provided.

EDIT
You have to declare at the top of source file that it uses Unicode literals.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Also prefix string being searched with **u**

```
a = u"6• 918417•12"
a = re.sub(u"[|•]", ",", a)
```

Comment: Thanks! But the bullet point char causes a problem saying Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file exportCass.py on line 76, but no encoding declared. What encoding should i declare?

Comment: When I add the utf-8 it works but now some of my single quotes ' started to show wierd. Henry's becomes Henry,,™ do you have any suggestions? @mhasan